# An array declared within the loop is not recognised outside it

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This is a segment from a program I'm working on for my school assignment.
The array pc2[ ] that I need can only (as far as I can see) be assigned within the loop and it prints correctly as well inside the loop. However, when I want to pass it to the function ultra1(), the array pc2[ ] is not recognized... 
If anyone has any ideas, please share them as quickly as possible. Thanks in advance!

```
void ultra()
{
    String pc[]={"Inspiron 14 3000 Series","Inspiron 15 3000 Series","Inspiron 11 3000 Series","Inspiron 15 - 7000 Series"};
    int bud[]={30190,28390,30990,81990,123990,186690,69990,48890,34990,38190};
    String pc3[]=new String[10];
    System.out.println("Please enter your maximum budget");
    int max=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(bud[i]<=max)
        {
            String pc2[]={pc[i],pc[i],pc[i],pc[i]};
            System.out.println(pc2[i]);
        }
    }
    ultra1(pc2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pc2` is not defined in the same scope as `ultra1(pc2);`.

`pc2` only exists here:

```
{
    String pc2[]={pc[i],pc[i],pc[i],pc[i]};
    System.out.println(pc2[i]);
}
```

You can define it in the same scope as `ultra1(pc2);`:

```
String pc2[];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    if(bud[i]<=max)
    {
        pc2[]={pc[i],pc[i],pc[i],pc[i]};
        System.out.println(pc2[i]);
    }
}
ultra1(pc2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's obviously because it's declared INSIDE the loop and therefore only a temporary object, which get's deleted as soon as the loop (or in your case even before that, at the end of the curly braces from the if) ends.

If you want to access it after that it needs to be a non-temporary object (or at least until it's called), so you'd need to declare it even before the for loop.

meaning it would look like this:

```
void ultra()
{
    String pc[] = {"Inspiron 14 3000 Series","Inspiron 15 3000 Series","Inspiron 11 3000 Series","Inspiron 15 - 7000 Series"};
    int bud[] = {30190,28390,30990,81990,123990,186690,69990,48890,34990,38190};
    String pc3[] = new String[10];
    System.out.println("Please enter your maximum budget");
    int max = sc.nextInt();
    String pc2[];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(bud[i] <= max)
        {
            pc2[] += {pc[i],pc[i],pc[i],pc[i]};
            System.out.println(pc2[i]);
        }
    }
    ultra1(pc2);
}
```

Comment: pc2[] = {pc[i],pc[i],pc[i],pc[i]};   -   Thanks, but now it's giving the errors, 'not a statement' and '; expected'. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah yeah, it was pc[] =... before, should work with pc[] +=... now